# Elaboration on the ImagingMemoryInstance struct in PIL

Tags: python-imaging-library

As a personal project I am trying to add cuda Backend to PIL as much as possible. I have however run into a little snafu. I am not able to understand how `Image.open()`. I am given to understand that all the actual data in PIL is stored in the `ImagingMemoryInstance` struct which is defined as follows -

```
struct ImagingMemoryInstance {
    /* Format */
    char mode[IMAGING_MODE_LENGTH]; /* Band names ("1", "L", "P", "RGB", "RGBA", "CMYK",
                                       "YCbCr", "BGR;xy") */
    int type;                       /* Data type (IMAGING_TYPE_*) */
    int depth;                      /* Depth (ignored in this version) */
    int bands;                      /* Number of bands (1, 2, 3, or 4) */
    int xsize;                      /* Image dimension. */
    int ysize;

    /* Colour palette (for "P" images only) */
    ImagingPalette palette;

    /* Data pointers */
    UINT8 **image8;  /* Set for 8-bit images (pixelsize=1). */
    INT32 **image32; /* Set for 32-bit images (pixelsize=4). */

    /* Internals */
    char **image;               /* Actual raster data. */
    char *block;                /* Set if data is allocated in a single block. */
    ImagingMemoryBlock *blocks; /* Memory blocks for pixel storage */

    int pixelsize; /* Size of a pixel, in bytes (1, 2 or 4) */
    int linesize;  /* Size of a line, in bytes (xsize * pixelsize) */

    /* Virtual methods */
    void (*destroy)(Imaging im);
};
```

I mainly have 3 questions

1. What exactly is the difference between `**image8`, `**image32`, `**image` and what to use when.
2. How does this struct come into picture when an image is read. I wasn't able to find any memory allocation in the source code.
3. And how can I convert the double pointers which contain the data to a single pointer. It would really become easier to write the kernels if I can convert them to a single pointer. 
   TIA

Comment: Don’t understanding anything about python /c/pillow. But what does : struct ImagingAccessInstance do in https://github.com/python-pillow/Pillow/blob/9b8202203aa5bd85ec89152c3d596ec8d8a56684/libImaging/Imaging.h#L78

Comment: I was not sure about how exactly the data is read, loaded and stored in PIL, so that I can convert that double pointer to a single pointer and also get a better understanding of how images are read. I was not able to make sense of the source code.

Comment: Can’t you just convert images to numpy array? NumPy uses the asarray() class to convert PIL images into NumPy arrays

Comment: No, what I am aiming for is that the user will simply mention the type of algorithm he wants to run, that is vanilla, simd accelerated or on cuda device using the python API, everything else should be taken care of internally so that's why I cannot

Comment: '''Pillow uses lazy loading. This means when you call Image.open(), the whole image isn't loaded into memory. Instead, only metadata is read. That is why you can get an exception in an unexpected place, like im.save() call. You can force image loading by calling im.load() and wrap it in try...catch. But be careful, you still can get exceptions even after loading. Most of them are caused by mode mismatch since most operations only work with particular modes (especially saving). You also can get MemoryError if your memory is exhausted.'''  Is this relevant to your question ?

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply, Yes that does clear a part of it. One of the major problems I am facing is to convert those double pointers to a flattened array with a single pointer. Can it be done ?

Comment: you mean : **image8, **image32, **image these are double pointers ??

Comment: Yes, I wanted to convert **image8, **image32 and **image to a flattened array so that I can pass them to the CUDA kernel with least hassle possible.

Comment: arent they already flat ?

Comment: I was not sure, and could not figure out a way to test that. That is the reason I asked over here. So it is just a pointer to the pointer to the image data  ?. I just wanted to confirm this.

Comment: I am at loss:  ImPlatform.h says  #define UINT8 unsigned char ;  Imaging.h says /* Data pointers */  UINT8 **image8; /* Set for 8-bit images (pixelsize=1). */ and then #define IMAGING_PIXEL_1(im,x,y) ((im)->image8[(y)][(x)]).

Comment: image8[(y)][(x)]) should be flat ? shouldn't it ? its not an arr type is char ?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. I don't think they are flattened. Because in the source code of PIL, have a look at `libImaging/AlphaComposite.c`. There, at every position `y`, the `image[y]` maps to a struct pointer that essentially contains `r, g, b, a` at a position, and this pointer is then incremented tin the `x` direction. So it's not flat I guess. I  just want to convert into a GPU friendly format. I suppose this would be the case for `**image8` and `**image32` as well